# including two functions in a javascript keypress

Tags: javascript

As a standard feature I keep a "don't allow returns" on form text fields using:

```
keypress="return event.keyCode != 13"
```

However I need to also only allow a numeric value in some field items using:

```
keypress="return inputLimiter(event,'Numbers')"
```

which ties in with a function.

So I need to tie the two together in the same keypress but can't find anything on if this is possible and when I've tried combining them neither work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Combine them with `&&`.

Using the same style syntax as you used in the question:

```
keypress="return event.keyCode != 13 && inputLimiter(event,'Numbers')"
```

In "real" JS:

```
window.onkeypress = function(){
    return event.keyCode != 13 && inputLimiter(event,'Numbers');
};
```

Comment: However i would suggest to avoid inline coding